# How to get country from Javascript Geolocation API or similar on a web page?

Tags: web-development, web, geo-location

I am trying to get precise location to country with a web page. I know there is geolocation using Javascript but that is latitude and longitude. I am trying for any way on a web page to get as precise a location as I can and convert it to country. I already got how to use IP addresses so not that way.

I would like but not need what sensors are being used. I may use Canvas in Javascript to find if a point is in a shape. It should be legal and with consent. I can custom code as much as needed to make it work. Maybe just a geolocation latitude and longitude points database for countries. I do not need province, just country. A goal is to limit countries I may sell to by a subset of WIPO Copyright Treaty. I do not know what platform or language I would use but probably just front-end and standard web page languages like Javascript. I would prefer a less spoofable version if possible, X E.

Comment: Not sure if this helps you but it might give you a hint though it is a Java project but at least you can rely on it as it is heavily used: https://github.com/westnordost/countryboundaries Edit: I think that whatever solution you use, it will be more or less spoofable.

Comment: Do you know of like a JSON or data set that that uses maybe?

Comment: I found GeoJSON, and know JSON, so that did help, but I needed to look it up, there are geoJSON files of earth political and states. Now just how to interpret in Javascript, X E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497728/get-country-from-latitude-longitude

Specifically I found from that:
https://www.weatherapi.com/pricing.aspx
Weather API can do geolocation to country for free.

It is free and allows 1 million calls per month. I may try some rectangles for longitude and latitude for larger, e.g. USA, countries, but those answer this question. If you want a paid version that answer set has some, but for me, a free version is better, X E.